# .NET how to open a wepage only when 3 users( or say more than one) login. I want it for procurement bidding application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

How to open a webpage only when 3 users( or say more than one) login. I want it for tender bidding application. There is a login page in which 3 procurement heads will login from distinct locations. When all 2 have successfully logged in then only a webpage which shows list of bidding amount received will open. please help

Comment: Can you please show us what you have attempted so far. Your question is too general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would implement two things:

- Websocket technology for pushing on client 'if-online' check
- Asp.net HttpHandler or ActionFilter if its MVC for detect user activity

So, after setting up you need to do:

1. When somebody is active - `HttpHandler`/`ActionFilte` handles it
2. Call websocket to force user-side code say 'i am online'
3. Create something like `session-activity` in your database with expires ~1 min
4. If your `session-activity` gather more then 2 hits force users by websocket open page with `session-activity-success-token`

---

Links:

[C# websockets realization](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

[Asp.net HttpHandlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms227675(VS.80))

[Asp.net MVC custom ActionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056(v=vs.98).aspx)